# How to pretty print HttpServletRequest and HttpServletResponse

Tags: java, http, tomcat, logging

I would like to add logging of requests and responses to a Java webapp which I am running within Tomcat 6. The intention is to produce a log file with output similar to what Wireshark would display. For example:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: www.bing.com
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.16 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/10.0.648.204 Safari/534.16
Accept: application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
```

I thought the best approach would be to use a Filter to capture the incoming HttpServletRequest and wrap the HttpServletResponse to allow the response content to be captured.

However, once I have an HttpServletRequest and HttpServletResponse is there a standard way to pretty print these objects out as they appeared on the wire?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tomcat supports so called [*Log Valve*](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/valve.html#Access_Log_Valve) - with a bit of formatting you can achieve what you want.

Also [Logback Access](http://logback.qos.ch/access.html) module aims to provide the same functionality but using Logback library.

Comment: I ended up using a modified version of the classes within Logback Access.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you can display the headers *exactly* as they would be sent, but if you enable Tomcat's request dumper valve you will see all of the headers sent and received.

Comment: Can you give me an example of what this ouput looks like? A tried to google this and couldn't find any examples.